# keep receiving "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" although everything seems right

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing phonegap application and I included phonegap push notifications plugin. I only used it as a prototype and the actual code is commented for production but It will be uncommented in the next release. For now I only want to make a production build with push notifications.

Here is what I already have in my apple profile

Certificates:

[image]

Ap id services:

[image]

Provisioning profile:

[image]

What else do I have to verify to stop receiving the warning email?

=======UPDATE

In xcode I have the following situation:

[image]

So after all there is something wrong, but for now I can't find the way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in xCode, when you select your project target under "capabilities" -> "Push Notifications" option is enabled and without errors.

In my case, it was turned off when migrating the project from xCode7 to 8.

Have to tried to disable and enable again the push capably?